# select ng-options list of years and see current year by default

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-options

I am using `select` and `ng-options` in angularjs to show a list of years that I construct myself.

**here is the [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/UVGwuJjEqgL2rS0hMVMF?p=preview).**

### My question is:

How to show the current year if you click on the dropdown list? I mean, supposing where are in 2017, when the user clicks, the default choice will be 2017 which will be situated in the middle of the list. the list will be in chronological order, starting from 20 years before current year and ending 20 years after current year. In other words, by clicking on the list the first visible default choice will be current year, and the user can roll up and down the years.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dates = {};
    $scope.years = [{value: 'Year', disabled: true}];
    var current_year = new Date().getFullYear();
    for(var i = current_year - 20; i <= current_year + 20; i++){
        $scope.years.push({value: i + ''});
    }

});
```

```html
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <label class="control-label">Year</label>
  <select name="startYear" ng-model="dates.startYear" id="startYear"
          ng-options="year.value as year.value disable when year.disabled for year in years"
          required>
      <option value="" disabled >Choose one</option>
  </select>
</div>
</body>
```

### update 1:

to clear up the misunderstanding, I want to center the list on the current year ONLY when the list is clicked, otherwise, the default SHOWN value is "choose one", but the default view should be centered on  current year when the list is opened.

### update 2:

Here is my dropdown menu:

http://preview.themeforest.net/item/cliptwo-bootstrap-admin-template-with-angularjs/full_screen_preview/10290688

Go to Forms / Form Wizard / Step 3 Billings

[image]

The default value in this above link is the word "Year", but when clicked, the list of years open up, and the list is not centered on the current year. Suppose we have 40 years before current year and 40 years after, then the user has to scroll down to current year interminably. 
So the idea is to center to the current year when the box is clicked.
here is the css file that is related to it, [link css](http://www.cliptheme.com/demo/clip-two/AngularJs-Admin/STANDARD/assets/css/styles.css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the current date first before getting the full year. The code is found below. Also, do modify your years.value to be an integer, and assign immediately to your ng-model (dates.startYear). And voila! Hope this helps.

```
   var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dates = {};
    $scope.years = [{value: 'Year', disabled: true}];
    for(var i = 1990; i <= 2040; i++){
        $scope.years.push({value: i});

    }

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();

    $scope.dates.startYear = n;
    console.log(n);

    });
```

Here is the plnkr [example](https://embed.plnkr.co/xbkwQkZ1knlufSxFOdXb/).

**UPDATE**

Here is a plnk [update](https://embed.plnkr.co/xbkwQkZ1knlufSxFOdXb/).

Basically, I put it in a function and fires on ng-click in the `select`.

Comment: i don't think it can work with your solution, i have tried it but doesn't work

Comment: yes thanks, but my question is a bit different. I mean, I want to center the list on the current year ONLY when the list is clicked, otherwise, the default SHOWN value is "choose one", by the default view should be centered on  current year.

Comment: i updated my question to clear up the misunderstanding

Comment: I think the sample work like the requirimets your a asking, if im missing something try clarify to me cause really i understand this -> the select by default must have current year, and 20 up and 20 down years.

Comment: oks i read you mean by default is null and when clicked gets the value ? suggested the curren year is that correct?

Comment: please see updated question and the real scenario at hand.